# Execute code with every page load w/ Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

It would be very useful to have a bit of code that executes every time any controller is called, such as authentication checks (see if user is logged in, check their username) and a priority for me, to record the page url and be able to echo out the previous page on next page load.

How would I go about executing something like this everytime a controller is called?

```
function page_load(){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('prev_page', $this->uri->uri_string());
    if($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()){
        $username = $this->tank_auth->get_username;
    } else {
        $username = 'Guest';
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a before [hook](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by extend'ing the Controller class.

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
        // Do any code you want run every time a controller loads
   }
}
?>
```

Then in your controllers where you would have extended CI_Controller you extend My_Controller instead.

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
  }
}
```

See documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

Comment: Using Hooks avoids the need to modify each controller: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Answer (score 4):

you are able to extend the core with CodeIgniter Hooks:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/hooks.html

That will execute with the core, so on every page!